# Background required for understanding Robust PCA and Low-Rank Sparse Decomposition

Tags: pca, references, robust, sparse

My current knowledge is Linear Algebra, basics of statistics and Machine Learning (Andrew Ng's ML Coursera).

I have a very good understanding of classic PCA and I know how to implement it in python or Matlab. However, every time I watch a video or read a paper about Robust PCA, my mind just goes blank due to many equations, notations and names I don't understand.

What background should I have in order to comfortably understand Robust PCA and low-rank sparse decomposition?

Comment: Welcome to our site! If you're interested in background reading you might need to do, consider adding the "references" tag

Comment: Is there a particular paper you can point to that is giving you trouble? I am not familiar with the term "Robust PCA" (and the Wikipedia page is pretty vague), while "low rank sparse decomposition" is non-unique, and could describe several methods. One concept you do not mention that *may* be relevant is [$L_1$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) optimization, which is common in both [robust statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Least_absolute_deviations) and [sparse approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sparse_approximation).

Comment: @GeoMatt22 I'm particularly interested in understanding Emmanuel's paper [link](statweb.stanford.edu/~candes/papers/RobustPCA.pdf)